# How to build a java project in TFS

Tags: java, maven, ant, tfs, build-process

I have a java project which depends on lots of libraries and two other java projects. All the projects along with the dependencies are in TFS 2015. I'd like to automate the build process and generate an executable jar files from my main project (which of course depends on other projects). What is the best approach? Where should I start? I've little experience with Ant and Maven.

Considering the fact that all the dependencies exist in the TFS, is maven still an option for making the build? or Maven is more suitable when I'd like to get the dependencies from an online repository?

Comment: Start by doing research and determining what build tool you want to use. Then start writing a build script using that tool. If you encounter problems that you can't solve yourself, ask questions here. As it stands, you're asking for a tool recommendation and a tutorial, which of which are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

To build a Eclipse project, you need to enable Ant or Maven builds on the build server:

1.Download and install a Java Development Kit.

2.Download and install Ant or Maven, depending on which build system you use. You can install both Ant and Maven on the same build machine if you use both build systems.

3.Download and install the TFS build extensions.

4.Set JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME or M2_HOME environment variables according to the Java, Ant, or Maven installation instructions.

Then create build definition and queue builds.

Detailed information, please refer to the article below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155784(v=vs.120).aspx